# What is the difference between certain JedisCommands which seem to be functionally equivalent to java.lang.String class

Tags: redis, jedis

What is the difference between `substr` command from JedisCommands and java.lang.String

[substr](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/redis/clients/jedis/2.0.0/jedis-2.0.0-javadoc.jar!/redis/clients/jedis/JedisCommands.html#substr%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis' `substr` command is performed in Redis server, so you don't need the whole string in you Java client to perform the operation.
E.g.: If it's a long string (e.g.: 1G) you don't need to fetch it all to get the first few bytes, reducing memory usage and the network connection between your Java client and Redis.

Another difference is that Java's `substr` is about characters, while Redis' `substr` is about bytes. That makes a huge difference when dealing with UTF-8 strings.